# get the div id after jquery sortable

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to drag and drop divs to respective placeholders(div) using JQuery `sortable`. I've tried using the following code to get the placeholder id from where the div being dragged.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){ 
    $(function() { 
        var item,from_placeholder_div_id;   
        $("#div-container").sortable({ 
            stop: function(event, ui) { 
                from_placeholder_div_id = $(ui.item).attr('id');
                alert("Widget moved from" + from_placeholder_div_id);
            } 
        });
    });
```

I also want to get the placeholder Id to which the div is moved. need some help on this

Answer (score 0):

You are saving `$(ui.item).attr('id')` to one variable and alerting another. You are saving it to `placeholder_div_id` and alerting `from_placeholder_div_id`

Changing it to `from_placeholder_div_id = $(ui.item).attr('id');` solves the problem.

Comment: that was just a typo...have updated it which was not my problem.. i want to get the `to_divId` i.e., to where the div is moved

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in the sender's id attribute:

```
from_placeholder_div_id = $(ui.sender).attr('id');
```